# Removing holes from polygons in R sf

Tags: r, polygon, r-sf

Is there a way to remove holes from a polygon in R with the package `sf`? I would be interested in solutions that include other packages, too.
Here's an example of a polygon with two holes.

```
library(sf)
outer = matrix(c(0,0,10,0,10,10,0,10,0,0),ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
hole1 = matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1),ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
hole2 = matrix(c(5,5,5,6,6,6,6,5,5,5),ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
pts = list(outer, hole1, hole2)
(pl1 = st_polygon(pts))
# POLYGON ((0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0), (1 1, 1 2, 2 2, 2 1, 1 1),(5 5, 5 6, 6 6, 6 5, 5 5))
```

Here's the figure:

```
plot(pl1, col="red")
```

[image: plot(pl1, col="red")]

Comment: Something like this? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224048/deleting-inner-holes-rings-borders-of-a-spatial-polygon-in-r

Comment: Yes, thank you. Now, is there a similar solution in `sf`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Following https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/609#issuecomment-357426716,
this could work:

```
library(sf)
outer = matrix(c(0,0,10,0,10,10,0,10,0,0),ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
hole1 = matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1),ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
hole2 = matrix(c(5,5,5,6,6,6,6,5,5,5),ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
pts = list(outer, hole1, hole2)
pl1 = st_geometry(st_polygon(pts))

plot(pl1)
```

[image]

```
pl2 <- st_multipolygon(lapply(pl1, function(x) x[1]))
plot(pl2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-10-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: How could I apply this to `shapefiles` objects? (I mean, remove holes within a `shapefile`)

Comment: @noriega You can load the sahpefile into R with `sf::st_read("your_shapefile.shp")` and use the method suggested by Ibusett.

Comment: Because of the `pl1[1]`, this creates `length(pl1)` (i.e., 3) copies of the first polygon - was that intended?

Comment: @jbaums You are right. That was a typo (now corrected). Also note that I had to add a `st_geometry` call on `pl1` for this to work (a `sfc_POLYGON` object is needed)

Comment: Also, the function reported by @AF7 seems nice and much more general, so I'd advice users to have a look.

Answer (score 25):

Package `nngeo` introduced a function to do this after this question was answered by @lbusett (and references him in the description, well done).

So you can use:

```
nngeo::st_remove_holes(your_sf_object)
```

See https://rdrr.io/cran/nngeo/man/st_remove_holes.html

Comment: Great solution! Thanks

Comment: I've been trying to find a replacement for rgeos::gUnaryUnion and I finally figured out that I needed to use sf::aggregate() and then nngeo::st_remove_holes() to get the equivalent of what gUnaryUnion() is doing (but soon to be deprecated)

Answer (score 9):

`sfheaders::sf_remove_holes()` can also do this

```r
sfheaders::sf_remove_holes(pl1)
POLYGON ((0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the `fill_holes()` function of the `smoothr` package might work as well.

Link: https://strimas.com/smoothr/reference/fill_holes.html

Demo:

```r
# fill holes smaller than 1000km2
p <- jagged_polygons$geometry[5]
area_thresh <- units::set_units(1000, km^2)
p_dropped <- fill_holes(p, threshold = area_thresh)
# plot
par(mar = c(0, 0, 1, 0), mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(p, col = "black", main = "Original")
plot(p_dropped, col = "black", main = "After fill_holes()")
```

[image]