# Make sf object out of polygons with holes and set crs

Tags: r, r-sf

With `contourLines()` I have extracted the 95% contour for my data. I would like to make an sf object with the correct crs. While I can't share my actual data set, I've adapted an example from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52654701/removing-holes-from-polygons-in-r-sf) to illustrate where I am stuck.

The main issue is that there is a hole in one of my polygons, but I can't figure out how to make an sf object where this hole is recognized *and* where I can specify the correct crs.

I am still fairly new to the sf-package and haven't been able to figure this out. Below is what I've tried so far. I've updated the output from `contourLines()` so that it looks like `pts`, where each list element is a matrix of point coordinates for a polygon. Using `st_polygon()` will remove the hole... but then I can't specify a crs:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# data example
outer1 <- matrix(c(0,0,4,0,4,4,0,4,0,0), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
hole   <- matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
outer2 <- matrix(c(5,5,5,6,6,6,6,5,5,5), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
pts <- list(outer1, hole, outer2)

# removes hole, but can't add crs 
# - nothing to transform with st_transform() 
# - st_set_crs() throws error:
#  > Error in UseMethod("st_crs<-") : 
#  >  no applicable method for 'st_crs<-' applied to an object of class "c('XY', 'POLYGON', 'sfg')"
pl1 <- st_polygon(pts)
plot(pl1, col = "red")
```

[image: image of pl1]

Alternatively, I could try make each list element a polygon and specify the correct crs... but then I can't figure out how to remove the hole:

```
pl2 <- pts %>% map(function(pts.x) {
  pts.x %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    set_colnames(c("x", "y")) %>%
    st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 32611) %>%
    summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
    st_cast("POLYGON")
}) %>%
  bind_rows
plot(pl2, col = "red")
```

[image: image of pl2]

Comment: you seem to have found your answer; so just a quick note - should you need to remove a  hole from a polygon consider `sf::st_sym_difference()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [this](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf3.html#geometrical-operations) example they use `st_polygon` then `st_sfc`. This seems to work

```
pl1 <- st_polygon(list(outer1, hole)) %>%
  st_sfc(crs = 32611)

#----------
Geometry set for 1 feature 
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 4 ymax: 4
projected CRS:  WGS 84 / UTM zone 11N
POLYGON ((0 0, 4 0, 4 4, 0 4, 0 0), (1 1, 1 2, ...
```

```
plot(pl1, col = 'red')
```

[image]

Comment: I've been pouring through that vignette, and still missed this -- many thanks for making this so clear.