# How to fill a shapefile with holes

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

Currently, I am processing spatial data in R.
https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/259089_2f5213f21003443994b28aab0a54cfd6.html

I created a time trade area by the method described on the above page.
However, the shapefile I created is perforated and incomplete.
I want you to tell me how to fill this hole.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10wJxptWxs59MB9KZVTsrs0biFYN9pOa-/view?usp=sharing

Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: `sfheaders::sf_remove_holes()`  https://stackoverflow.com/a/64056292/7547327

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say, what's the exact issue here, as the information is not that clear.
But looking at the file, you shared [screenshot from shapefile in QGIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjIaa.png) it seems that this is just a single layer for a a travel time bracket, e.g. 05-20 min travel time. Then it also makes sense that the layer is "Doughnut-shaped". This code produces several separate shapefiles, each for a different travel-time.

Could you share your code, so one could see, how you arrived at your result?
Can you share which code you used for setting up the intervals, similar to this:

```
iso <- osrmIsochrone(loc = c(151.207049, -33.886475), breaks = seq(from = 0,to = 30, by = 5))
class(iso)
```

If you really just want a *single* shapefile, without a hole inside, try chainging  `breaks = seq(from = 0,to = 30, by = 5)`  to `seq(from = 0,to = 30, by = 1)` and make sure, it starts with `from = 0` , not with something like `from = 5`.